# What should my expectations be when flagging in need of moderator intervention?

Tags: support, flags, moderators

What should one's expectations be when flagging *in need of moderator intervention*?  In the past ten years, I have done so twice, however, I do not believe I ever received any sort of acknowledgement either time.  I recognize the moderators are busy and am not complaining but just wish to better level-set my expectations.  Also, if I was sent a response, how would receive it, and is there anything that shows the flags I have submitted? Thank you

[image: Modal before submitting]
[image: Modal after submitting]

Comment: You can see all the flags you've ever raised, along with status and mod response (if applicable), in your [flag summary page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current).

Comment: @bobble  Thanks for the link.  It doesn't show any, however, I never made a flag on Meta but only Stackoverflow so maybe that is to expected.  How were you made aware that such a link existed and is their similar pages on the other Stack sites?  I tried using https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/233594 without success.  Thanks again.

Comment: The number at the end is your user ID, which on SO is 1032531 for you. I used `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current` because that will give any signed-in user who clicks on the link their own flag summary page. Alternatively, go to your profile and click "X helpful flags" (near the "X posts edited" and "X votes cast" upper-right).

Comment: Head on over to Stack Overflow, and click your avatar in the top right. On the right side of your screen, you should see a "(number) helpful flags" item. Click it! Or, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current).

Comment: Thanks booble and Spevacus.  Yes, I do seem them now!  Evidently I made three flags but the first was 7 years ago and I forgot.  Also, on the one I made a few months ago, I did receive a response but just was unaware.

Comment: Isn't there a meta question that explains the flag summary page?

Comment: I've mostly used this flag when someone makes a post with a username that is offensive.  I believe I've seen other meta posts about what to do with users that have offensive "loophole" usernames to bypass profanity filters, and believe this was the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your flag will, sometime between a few minutes and a few weeks, depending on site moderator workload, be marked either "helpful" or "declined" and an optional message explaining the decision on the flag summary page ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current) on Meta.SE), which you can get to by opening your profile and clicking the "*n* helpful flags" link near the top right:

[image: profile page excerpt with "261 helpful flags" emphasized]

Most helpful flags don't receive a comment, though some do.  Declined flags generally receive an explanation of why they were declined.  There is no notification when a flag is handled, though a declined flag will result in a message for you the next time you open the flag dialog.

The time to process will vary depending on the complexity of the flag to handle.  Moderators can select flags from the custom flag queue out of order, so simpler flags tend to be handled more quickly.  The most complex flags can take well over an hour each to handle, so they may be put off until a moderator (who, as you probably know, are volunteers) has time to dedicate to handling it properly.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, Nice explanation.  I've since learned that a moderator did get back to me on one case and the other case was very recent and was not surprised by not having a response.